# How to count all elements where custom attribute has a certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I determine the total amount of `div`'s in this `td` where `data-something` is "yes"?

```
<td id='tableData'>
  <div class="test" data-something="yes"></div>
  <div class="test" data-something="no"></div>
  <div class="test" data-something="yes"></div>
</td>
```

Comment: I believe you know that `div` elements should have closing tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with:

```
var len = $("#tableData div[data-something='yes']").length;
```

or:

```
var len = $("#tableData div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("something") == "yes";
}).length;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7c4cA/

Comment: @user784637 Please provide an example in JSFiddle, we can check where is the problem.